# Node.js Heroku deployment error

Tags: node.js, heroku

I've tried to attach the build log but stack over flow was keep throwing errors, so i will go ahead and skip the build log. As far as the build log goes, there wasn't an error.

As you can see there is no error generated while building the system on heroku's side. I did everything that my domain name company told me to.

However, when I go to my custom url, `www.example.com`, I see an error:

> Heroku | No such app
>
> There is no app configured at that hostname.
>   Perhaps the app owner has renamed it, or you mistyped the URL.

The url that heroku gives me works but when I connect it to my namecheap domain, it keeps giving me that `Heroku | No such app`-error.

Comment: Have you tried `http://example.herokuapp.com/` rather than (default?) `https://example.herokuapp.com`?  [http rather than https]